# Integration between Keycloak and Google Cloud Logging

Tags: java, log4j, keycloak, google-cloud-logging

### Context

Hi everyone, I'm trying to set logs from Keycloak server to Google Cloud Logging. I've already read the follow documentation:

- [*google-cloud-logging overview*](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-logging/latest/overview)
- [*Setting Up Cloud Logging for Java*](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java)

But I don't understand how can I do this to Keycloak.

I'm using the follow documentation [*Keycloak on Quarkus*](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/21.0.2/quarkus/README.md) and I think that Keycloak is using Log4j based on the follow [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/21.0.2/quarkus/runtime/pom.xml).

#### Expected result

I can see logs from Keycloak 21.0.2 on Google Cloud Logging